# How to split a java string with a regex?

Tags: java, regex, split

I am struggling a bit with splitting a string.

Here is an example of an input and the correct output I want:

Input: `"Hope you're doing well! I am doing ok. "`  <--- A few spaces after the period

Output:

```
[Hope, " ", you're, " ", doing, well, "!" , " ", "I", " ", 
 "am", " ", "doing", " ", "ok", "." , " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
```

I want an output that splits all the words into it's own index (even if it includes an apostrophe). Also, I want all the spaces and punctuation(?, !, ., " ") to have their own index in the array.

Here's what I've tried: I have taken a string message and used the split function. I have used a regex  which is giving me almost the correct output, but it's not accounting for extra spaces after the period.

The regex I used:

```
"\\b |(?=\\p{Punct})|(?<=\\p{Punct}) | "
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it but it is rather unorthodox.

```
String str = "Hope you're doing well! I am doing ok. ";
```

Establish a regex for all the punctuation, spaces, etc  you want using a capture group.

```
String regex = "([!\\s\\.])";
```

Then replace each occurrence of those surrounded by a non-relevant character. In this case I used a `#`.  You could actually use several characters together as a split delimiter.

Then split on that character.

```
String[] tokens = str.replaceAll(regex, "#$1#").split("#");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Prints

```
[Hope,  , you're,  , doing,  , well, !, ,  , I,  , am,  , doing,  , ok, ., ,  ]
```

You can get rid of the `empty` strings `("")` as follows:

```
tokens = Arrays.stream(tokens).filter(s->!s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: No need to escape the `.` period inside a character class, and no need to create a capture group. Use `regex = "[!\\s.]"` and `replaceAll(regex, "#$0#")`.

Comment: Creating a new string before splitting is a waste, and fails if the input happens to contain the `#` marker character. This can be [done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61981098/5221149) with lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define what constitutes the characters of a "word", and anything else should become a separate token. Here I've defined word-characters as letters, numbers, apostrophes, and dashes, so the separate tokens are anything but those:

```regex
[^\p{L}\p{N}'-]
```

Then you build a regex using zero-with positive lookahead and lookbehind for the non-word characters, with a little extra to make sure we don't do a zero-width match at beginning or end of input.

```regex
(?<!^)(?=[^\p{L}\p{N}'-])|(?<=[^\p{L}\p{N}'])(?!$)
```

As Java code, that would be:

```java
String input = "Hope you're doing well! I am doing ok.     ";

String regex = "(?<!^)(?=[^\\p{L}\\p{N}'-])|(?<=[^\\p{L}\\p{N}'])(?!$)";
String[] tokens = input.split(regex);

System.out.println(Arrays.stream(tokens).map(s -> '"' + s + '"')
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")));
```

*Output*

```json
["Hope", " ", "you're", " ", "doing", " ", "well", "!", " ", "I", " ",
 "am", " ", "doing", " ", "ok", ".", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
```